# Merging two Tubes

Tags: cinema4d

I want to create an object with one tube plus another half like in the screenshot but as you can see there is intersecting polygons.

I have tried connect objects, connect and bool but none solves my problem. What is the best way to create the form I'm looking for?

[image]

Comment: Ive never used Cinema4D (Lite doesn't really function well for me and don't own the pro) but probably need to combine the flat ones and then extrude them. In AutoCAD this would be combining Polylines and then Extruding but not sure what its called in Cinema4D

Comment: Doing Boolean operations on pure polygonal data will just give you grief. There's no way for it to work well it can only work adequately.

Answer (score 3):

option 1:

- create 2 tubes and cut anything you want to cut from the second tube

[image]

- select both tubes > rmb > connect obejcts and delete

[image]

- select common edges

[image]

- rmb > stitch and sew

[image]

- while holding CTRL drag from one point to another

[image]

- do the same on another side
- select some polygons and hide them to see "the wall" between tubes

[image]

[image]

- delete the wall
- unhide polygons
- profit

option 2:

- create 2 tubes and cut anything you want to cut from the second tube
- select contour edges on half-ring

[image]

- mesh > commands > edge to spline

[image]

- select ONLY outside edges on the other ring
- mesh > commands > edge to spline
- select both splines
- create a "spline mask"
- put both splines into the mask
- in the mask options choose XZ (along Y)

[image]

- press C
- select the inner edge of the ring > egde to spline
- select both splines > rmb > connect objects and delete
- create an extrusion
- profit

Comment: Hi soundsbeard welcome to GD.SE. I took the liberty of editing your answer to convert the links to actual images, to make it easier to understand your answer.

Comment: donno how to get 10 damn exp

Comment: No problem. Keep contributing with good answers and good questions. If you want to know more about the site, please see [help].